Как передать функцию на страницу в Express JS
У меня есть функция по добавлению массива в базу данных, так мне её надо как-то использовать на странице.
index.js
function addSMPdb(data) {
    const con = new sync(CONFIG);
    const query = 'INSERT INTO obekt SET ?';
    con.query(query, data, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Ошибка вставки:', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Данные успешно вставлены | '+results);
        }
    });
}

app.get('/test', (req, res) => res.render('test', { addSMPdb } ));

test.ejs
<button id="myButton">Aga</button>

<script>

    document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        addSMPdb(formData);
    });
</script>

Ошибка после нажатия на кнопку в консоли
ReferenceError: addSMPdb is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (test:16:9)

Подскажите, как можно это исправить.

Не стоит таким заниматься. Вы должны делать запрос с данными на бэкэнд и там уже выполнять данную функцию.
